# calling an oracle db function from C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an issue of calling an oracle function from C#. I want to know how to define parameters (in and out) in C# for the Oracle function. In Oracle function parameters have been defined as following. Is there an error in the way I have defined the parameters in the Oracle function. I appreciate help from anyone.

```
create or replace FUNCTION         
"IS_GEC_AVAILABLE" (policyNo IN varchar2,startDate in number,EndDate in number)
return number
as
isGECMemberCount number :=0;
....

begin
.....
.....

return isGECMemberCount;

EXCEPTION
when others then
return 0;
end;
```

Comment: this link might help http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/460653/Call-oracle-function-from-csharp-code

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle function defined like in your example this C# syntax worked:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
...

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.CommandText = "IS_GEC_AVAILABLE";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Decimal, 0, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("policyNo", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1, "X", ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("startDate", OracleDbType.Decimal, 0, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("EndDate", OracleDbType.Decimal, 0, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("result: " + cmd.Parameters[0].Value);
    con.Close();
```

It's important to define *returned* parameter as first or add `cmd.BindByName = true;`. 
Also for varchar2 parameters it's important to define *size* correctly.